# Kill session on another machines by Session ID

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to kill session  on another machine if the new session started with the same username as the username in a session that running on another machine,i`m storing the 'username's and sessions id as applications variables and deleting them when session over

> Sesion_Start()
>
> if (Application[Session["Username"].ToString()] != null)
>
> ```
>             {
>                 string id =  Application[Session["Username"].ToString()].ToString(); 
>
>                                     //kill the session
>
>
>
>                 Application[Session["Username"].ToString()] = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
>
>             else
>                 Application[Session["Username"].ToString()] = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
> ```
>
> Session_End()
>
> Application[Session["Username"].ToString()] = null;

So Bassicly,what i left it`s find session in some session collection and kill it,anyone have ideas how to do it?

Comment: Do you see how your code is formatted? What thoughts you have about it?

Answer (score 1):

Store session data on a database server by changing the mode attribute to SqlServer

```
<sessionState mode="SqlServer" 
  sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa; password=" 
  cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

then query the session database

```
select SessionItemShort,
SessionItemLong
from ASPStateTempSessions
```

Comment: I cannot use session state mode="sqlserver",because this way session_end will never get fired up and i use it for another stuff.so still I wonder if it posiablle to kill sessions in C#